# Searching in lists of lists --- get answers for each list --- just want one answer

Tags: python-3.x, list, discord.py

I want to check if the ctx.author is connected to any voice channel on this discord guild.
The bot does that, but for each channel where ctx.author is not, the bot sends the message "You need to be connected to a voice-channel!"
How do I create a list from the member lists that the bot then check?

```py
voice_channel_list = ctx.guild.voice_channels
for voice_channels in voice_channel_list:
    if not ctx.author in voice_channels.members:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=("You need to be connected to a voice-channel!")))
    elif ctx.author in voice_channels.members:
        pass #does something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over the voice channels, [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) has a [`voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice) attribute that you can check directly.

```
if ctx.author.voice is None:
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=("You need to be connected to a voice-channel!")))
else:
    pass #does something
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. When I search for something in the documentation I don't find it. 